Python Bert is failing at preprocessed_inputs = preprocessor(text_input). A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an dtype
I'm tying to load bert model and text_input is printing
<KerasTensor shape=(None,), dtype=string, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor_54>
and preprocessor is also loading but still getting this error.
ValueError: A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. You cannot convert it to a NumPy array.
Code
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string)
print(text_input)
# Load the BERT preprocessing model from TensorFlow Hub
preprocessor_url = "https://kaggle.com/models/tensorflow/bert/TensorFlow2/en-uncased-preprocess/3"

try:
    preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer(preprocessor_url)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error loading the BERT preprocessing model:", e)

# Check if the preprocessor is None
if preprocessor is None:
    print("Preprocessor is None. There was an error loading the model.")
else:
    # Preprocess the text inputs using the BERT preprocessing layer
    preprocessed_inputs = preprocessor(text_input)

Stack trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayazbism/PycharmProjects/hate-speech-detection/hate_speech_detection.py", line 394, in <module>
    preprocessed_inputs = preprocessor(text_input)
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/src/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 899, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py", line 250, in call
    result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 55, in smart_cond
    return false_fn()
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py", line 252, in <lambda>
    lambda: f(training=False))
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 817, in _call_attribute
    return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/core/function/polymorphism/function_type.py", line 583, in canonicalize_to_monomorphic
    _make_validated_mono_param(name, arg, poly_parameter.kind,
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/core/function/polymorphism/function_type.py", line 522, in _make_validated_mono_param
    mono_type = trace_type.from_value(value, type_context)
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/core/function/trace_type/trace_type_builder.py", line 185, in from_value
    ndarray = value.__array__()
  File "/home/ayazbism/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/keras_tensor.py", line 61, in __array__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. You cannot convert it to a NumPy array.

Please share the reason. why I'm getting this error. is it due to python version because bert code is same at all places.

The code above works fine on Colab. The error is probably caused by your Keras/Tensorflow installation. Try installing tensorflow-text:
!pip install tensorflow-text=={your version of TF}
